# Python Scipy optimize does not respect constraints

Tags: python, scipy, scipy-optimize, scipy-optimize-minimize

Using Python scipy function Optimize/Minimize, constraint is not respected despite the optimization finishing as "Optimization terminated successfully".

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize

def obj_fun(x):
   # I do here calculations depending on x and put the result in r
   fr = f1(x)
   pr = f2(x)
   r = abs((fr/pr)-1)
   print(r)
   return r


constr = {'type':'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: obj_fun(x)-0.01}
res = minimize(obj_fun,(0,0,0,0,0), constraints=constr, method='SLSQP')
```

And it returns:

```
7.41234e-05
7.41256e-05
...
...
7.4567e-05

fun: 7.4567e-05
...
message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
nfev: 161
nfit:19
njev:15
status:0
success: True
x: array([6.5, 6.5, 3.5, 3.6, 3.5])
```

As you can see, I printed the value inside the objective function just to confirm what is calculated. And all the values are much smaller than 0.01 until it stops but still gives a "success" status somehow...

Tried different solvers and different ways to write the constraints but my understanding is that the constraints should mean: `(obj_fun(x) - 0.01) > 0` but clearly the optimization answer is much smaller than 0.01.

Comment: Interesting case, please share the content of `obj_fun` or a proxy that can reproduce the error. I would like to give it a shot.

Comment: Thanks - it's quite hard to provide the content as it uses many classes, etc. I will try to add something by this evening (GMT) so that you can replicate. In the meantime, I printed the value inside the objective function as shown in the edit and it really calculates the right value but just suddenly stops and calls it "success" despite not respecting the constraints...

Comment: Can you also add examples of `f1` and `f2` to reproduce the issue?

Comment: I will try to add that information ASAP, need to simply a lot the code for that otherwise too long. But I feel my Scipy is really full of bugs. I tried to add boundaries and it's not respected as well. My version is Scipy 0.19.0 which sounds quite old...

Comment: Your objective function is not continuously differentiable due to the use of abs and thus violates the mathematical assumptions of the algorithms under the hood of scipy.minimize.